# How to add namespace suffix in request of web method name in c# web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, soap

How to add  xmlns:xsi in  helloworld method in request of web method name in c# web service

here is the code:

````
< soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >

  <  soap:Body >

    < HelloWorld xmlns="http://example.org/"  xmlns:xsi="http://example.org/" >
      < tst test="string" tester="string" / >
    < /HelloWorld >
  < /soap:Body >
< /soap:Envelope >```
````

Comment: your question is not clear can you please add some code what is the issue and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please look now

Comment: from where you need to add namespace please show the code what you are trying to do here